# How I make a function with unlimited parameters in js?

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
function add(args_list){
   var total;
   return totatl; // Output should be Total of args list
}
add(25,25,10); // 60
```

How I make this function with unlimited parameters

Comment: Pass an array to the function

Comment: Can't i make that without array...?

Comment: No I don't know any other way.

Comment: Ok...Thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function add(...theArgs) {
  const sum = theArgs.reduce((acc, arg) => acc + arg, 0);
  console.log('Sum is', sum);
  
}
    
add();  // 0
add(5); // 1
add(5, 6, 7); // 3
```

Note: theArgs is an array, but you pass parameters to the function as you normally would, not as an array.

Comment: Wow that's great. I didn't know about that.

Comment: feels bad having 3 dots there.